# ffmpeg: Add a New audio track to existing file

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, encoding

I've manually created a stereo mixdown oft some 5.1 DTS tracks. Now I would like to add the new audio track to the original movie file, without dropping the old audio tracks.

My problem appears to be that I either miss to hand ffmpeg the correct mapping of the tracks (the file has a two audio tracks already and a number of subtiles, which appear to count too), so that I receive the "Number of stream maps must match the number of output streams" (quoted from memory), or I even geht the whole stream/map concept wrong.

Is there any good explanation for what I'm trying to do?
I'd even read a whole text about the topic, the documentation in ffmpeg.org just isn't that helpful in this case.

To be more specific: I want to know if there is any way to make ffmpeg display the actual stream mapping of a file and how can I merge my stereo track into it?

Everything I've found so far deals with silent videos vor replacling an audio track, which is not what I want to do.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -i audio.dts -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

The default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior only chooses one stream per stream type, so in this case you have to use [`-map`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) to tell it which streams you want.

The input file index starts counting from 0, so using `-map 0` will choose all streams from the first input (`input.mkv`), and `-map 1` will choose all streams from the second input (`audio.dts`).

The result is that `output.mkv` will contain all of the streams from both inputs. Using `-c copy` will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the streams, so they will simply be re-muxed without additional re-encoding.

Comment: Why didn't you also set the language of the audio track? I think it can be specified by just adding for example (for English): `-metadata:s:a:1 language=eng -metadata:s:a:1 title="ENG"` to the command just before `output.mkv`. `s:a:1` sets the second audio track, it starts counting at 0 and you need to change that number as needed.